# Using decorators with NextJS and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, next.js, inversion-of-control, typedi

I'm trying to add dependency injection to my NextJS solution using TypeDI.

In tsconfig.js I have the following set

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

But when I compile I get the following error:

> Error: error: Unexpected token `@`. Expected this, import, async,
> function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator,
> function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string, regexp, `
> for template literal, (, or an identifier
> | 8 | @Service()   | ^

The only solution I've found for this is to add the following to a babel config file along with the plugins and babel itself.

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

This looks like it might actually make the decorators work, however NextJS 12 has replaced Babel with SWC and also results in a ton of compiler messages which don't look good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you happen to find a solution to this? If so, do you mind posting it as an answer to your own question? I'm running into the same issue and it would be great to know if there's an easy solution

Comment: No, for a while I started using TSyringe which worked however in the end I found it was adding far more complexity to the solution vs any real gain.